# Video capture from usb or firewire

Tags: video, capture

I want to capture video files from an older Canon digital tape camcorder. I have a dell computer with usb and firewire ports. I have 2 cables; one firewire to usb and one firewire to firewire so I can hook my camera to my pc. I need an easy way to capture video from the tapes to the computer. Is there an easy way that does not require a degree from MIT?

Answer (score 4):

A straightforward way to extract video from the camera is to use the `dvgrab` tool.

Install it with `sudo apt-get install dvgrab`.

There is a tutorial on how to use it on [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FireWire/dvgrab).

Give that a try, and if you get stuck, edit your question to describe what you have tried and what went wrong.